# husky / lint-staged not running custom command or printing errors

Tags: npm, package.json, pre-commit-hook, husky, lint-staged

I am trying to upgrade from husky@4.8 and lint-staged@11.2 to husky@8.0 and lint-staged@@13.1 for my Nx repo. It seems that the only configuration I used to need was the following in package.json:

```
"scripts: {
    "lint:fix": "ng lint -- --fix && npm run prettier:fix",
}
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -e $HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,js,css,md,html}": "npm run lint:fix",
    "relative": true
  }
```

This no longer works with the new husky and lint-staged. I followed [this](https://duncanlew.medium.com/getting-started-with-husky-and-lint-staged-for-pre-commit-hooks-c2764d8c9ae) tutorial and installed husky: `npx husky-init && npm install`, installed lint-staged: `npm install --save-dev lint-staged`, modified the .husky/pre-commit file:

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"
npx lint-staged
```

and added the .lintstagedrc.json file:

```
{
  "*.ts": [
    "prettier --write",
    "eslint"
  ],
  "*.html": [
    "eslint",
    "prettier --write"
  ],
  "*.scss": "prettier --write"
}
```

When I make a new commit it seems to run. However it looks like this command either runs on every library or every staged file (I have a lot of libraries). When I change the file contents to:

```
{
    "*.{js,ts,json,scss,md}": ["npm run lint:fix"]
}
```

it takes a while to run (though it seems to run and fix the linting) AND I don't get the output of my `ng lint -- --fix` command. If I go into the .husky/pre-commit file and change `npx lint-staged` to `npm run lint:fix`, it runs the `ng lint -- --fix` command, fixes what it can and prints out linting errors. However, the error doesn't prevent the commit and I have to commit any new changes that the linter fixed. With the old versions I didn't need to do this. Also I didn't need to commit a .husky/pre-commit file into my repo. (I see some workarounds that have a `postinstall` script that generates this file for the user).

How can I utilize lint-stage and husky newest versions to run my custom npm command so I can call ng lint like in the older versions and block commits on errors? Should I just use the older versions? Also what benefit do the newer versions provide?